# How to define a Many-To-Many relationship using CakePHP3?

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I want to create a many to many releationship between three tables in CakePHP 3. By defining this releation in my controller and models, but I can't get this off.

My three tables are as follow:

**Table one: Users**

```
ID   Name
1    gert
2    henk
```

**Table two: Clothes**

```
ID   Name
1    jacket
2    jeans
```

This is the table where I have saved the link between the Users table and the Clothes table. So now can a user have multiple clothes and the different clothes can belong to multiple users.

**Table three: Users_has_clothes**

```
ID   UserId(forKey)   ClothesId(forKey)
1    1                1
2    2                1
3    1                2
```

I have tried to follow the instructions from the official CakePHP site [Using the ‘through’ Option](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#using-the-through-option), but it is still not clear to me.

Comment: You should try to follow CakePHP naming conventions, it would save you from lots of trouble (like naming the table `users_clothes` and the key `user_id` and `clothe_id`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use the `through` option if your join table does not have extra fields (it looks like it does not in your example).

If you can, you should follow CakePHP naming conventions, meaning  your join table should be named `users_clothes`, and its two fields should be `user_id` and `clothe_id`. See [CakePHP documentation](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/associations.html#belongstomany-associations) for more details about naming convention. With these conventions, the following code would work:

```
public class User extends Table {
    public function initialize (array $config) {
         $this->belongsToMany('Clothes');
    }
}
// Same for table Clothe
```

If you really need to keep the names as they are currently, you should add the following extra options:

```
public class User extends Table {
    public function initialize (array $config) {
         $this->belongsToMany('Clothes', [
            'joinTable' => 'Users_has_clothes',
            'foreignKey' => 'UserId', 
            'targetForeignKey' => 'ClotheId'
        ]);
    }
}
// Same for Clothe (switch foreignKey and targetForeignKey)
```